# Two blogs one page

Tags: blog, columns

The idea is basically to create a blog, and have status updates/quotes beside the blog in a separate column.

How does one go about making that happen?

EDIT:
The goal is not to create two separate wordpress sites. The idea is to have two columns on one page: One column of blog-posts and another column of status updates/quotes (aka very short texts).

Comment: Sorry but that isn't very clear.  Are you asking how to run two separate WP sites at once?  Two authors on one blog?  Two sites in a single WP multisite install?  Can you describe your goal a bit more clearly, including what you have tried that did not work.

Comment: As I have only used drupal so far and never tried wordpress I would not know where to start :-) That is why I ask here. I have tried to reformulate my question to fit the requirements :-) Sorry for the hassle.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways to create a two-column design in WordPress, where most typically you would use a theme that already has support for doing so.

This page has a pretty nice listing of the different ways that you can create a two-column layout on your site: http://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/how-to-create-columns-in-posts/

You can also go to the [wordpress.org Themes Directory](https://wordpress.org/themes/tag-filter/) and search using their Tags system to narrow down themes that will help you do what you are trying to accomplish. For example:

[image: Choosing a Two-Column Theme]